# How to handle not found exceptions when using @ParamConverter in Symfony4?

Tags: symfony, symfony-4.2

For example, I converter an entity in my update method in a controller,

```
public function show(Post $post): Response
```

According to the spec,

> If no Post object is found, a 404 Response is generated;

Symfony will return a 404 response directly, but it only applies for a dev environment.

In a prod environment, it only throws an unhandled exception error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught 
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException:
>   App\Entity\Post object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation.

How can I handle the exception in a prod environment?

Comment: Did you cleared the cache? `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: I've tried that, but it didn't work. I didn't handle the exception, so it will return 200 and a Fatal error in a prod env.

Comment: Quick solution? Add defaults to that route and set your $post=null because then it will never intercept, because null value is allowed. Then you can check inside your controller (if you have more then one, where you have this problem, use traits) and throw whatever you want or redirect to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That sounds good to me, but I still wonder if there's a better solution.